# How can I process variable substitutions in bash?

Tags: python, bash, perl, sed, environment-variables

So I have some files that contain placeholder values like `@USER@` or `@SHELL@` (all-caps variable names, enclosed in @'s, representing environment variable names). What I want to do is replace those placeholders with actual values of the environment varables they reference.

In the past when I've seen this sort of thing done, the specific variables are usually hard-coded, eg:

```
sed -e 's/@SOME_VARIABLE@/$SOME_VALUE/' <infile >outfile
```

But that won't work for my current use-case as I want to more flexibly support arbitrary substitutions. I wrote this code in python which does exactly what I want:

```
import re
import fileinput

from os import environ
from sys import stdout

pat = re.compile(r'@([A-Z_]+)@')

for line in fileinput.input():
    stdout.write(pat.sub(lambda match: environ[match.group(1)], line))
```

But I'd prefer not to use python if I can help it. Surely there's a way to do this with a perl or sed one-liner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`perl -pe 's/\@(\w+)\@/$ENV{$1}/g'` would be one way to do the job.

If you want to throw an error if a variable mentioned in the file doesn't exist in the environment, you could use

```
perl -pe 's/\@(\w+)\@/die "$1 not found\n" unless exists $ENV{$1}; $ENV{$1}/eg'
```

Comment: Is there a way to make perl complain if the variable is undefined? Would be better than silently leaving blanks in my file if my env vars are set wrong.

Comment: the fail status from `die` should be enough to make `make` bail out as well.

Comment: This also works ans is shorter: `perl -pe 's/@([A-Z_]+)@/$ENV{$1} or die "$1 undefined"/eg'` (I realize they're not quite semantically identical, but my use case doesn't require "variables set to empty value" so it's ok)

Comment: @Robru how about variables with the value 0? Be careful. I would use my version in tooling, "shorter" isn't that important.

Comment: Ah, the falsiness of *string* "0" is terrifying, I'm used to python where only empty strings are false. At least in my use case I'm only substituting long strings like usernames and paths, so for me having an error raised for empty strings is a feature. I don't anticipate needing to expand to "0" at any point.

Comment: @Robru you could use my version with `length` in place of `exists` to fail on empty string but succeed on 0.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. What I don't like about yours is the way it says `$ENV{$1}` twice, the redundancy irks me a bit. It occurs to me that if I ever do need `"0"` my shorter way will complain loudly so it's not like I'll be stuck with a silent failure that's hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it's been too long since I've played with perl, this does exactly what I want:

```
perl -pe 's/@([A-Z_]+)@/$ENV{$1} or die "$1 undefined"/eg' <infile >outfile
```

And then in a Makefile you need to escape the dollar signs:

```
envsubst = perl -pe 's/@([A-Z_]+)@/$$ENV{$$1} or die "$$1 undefined"/eg'

install:
    $(envsubst) <infile1 >outfile1
    $(envsubst) <infile2 >outfile2
```